# PHP crashed on server

Tags: php, linux, crash

abrt_version:  2.0.8
cgroup:
cmdline:        /usr/bin/php-cgi -c /var/www/vhosts/system/xxxxxx.com/etc/php.ini
executable:    /usr/bin/php-cgi
kernel:        2.6.32-358.23.2.el6.x86_64
pid:            26070
pwd:            /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper
time:          Thu 26 Jun 2014 12:33:23 AM CDT
uid:            10002
username:      xxxx

sosreport.tar.xz: Binary file, 2232552 bytes

`environ:
:PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
:PP_CUSTOM_PHP_INI=/var/www/vhosts/system/xxxx.com/etc/php.ini
:PP_CUSTOM_PHP_CGI_INDEX=fastcgi`

`limits:
:Limit                    Soft Limit          Hard Limit          Units

:Max cpu time              unlimited            unlimited            seconds 
:Max file size            unlimited            unlimited            bytes

:Max data size            unlimited            unlimited            bytes

:Max stack size            10485760            unlimited            bytes

:Max core file size        0                    unlimited            bytes

:Max resident set          unlimited            unlimited            bytes

:Max processes            30482                30482                processes
:Max open files            1024                4096                files

:Max locked memory        65536                65536                bytes

:Max address space        unlimited            unlimited            bytes

:Max file locks            unlimited            unlimited            locks

:Max pending signals      30482                30482                signals 
:Max msgqueue size        819200              819200              bytes

:Max nice priority        0                    0

:Max realtime priority    0                    0

:Max realtime timeout      unlimited            unlimited            us`

`maps:
:00400000-006c3000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 24305                              /usr/bin/php-cgi
:008c2000-00918000 rw-p 002c2000 08:02 24305                              /usr/bin/php-cgi
:00918000-00931000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
:00b17000-00b21000 rw-p 00317000 08:02 24305                              /usr/bin/php-cgi
:017fd000-01bd8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
:33a2800000-33a2872000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 1996                          /lib64/libgcrypt.so.11.5.3
:33a2872000-33a2a71000 ---p 00072000 08:02 1996                          /lib64/libgcrypt.so.11.5.3
:33a2a71000-33a2a72000 r--p 00071000 08:02 1996                          /lib64/libgcrypt.so.11.5.3
:33a2a72000-33a2a75000 rw-p 00072000 08:02 1996                          /lib64/libgcrypt.so.11.5.3
:33a2c00000-33a2c13000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 24544                          /usr/lib64/libexslt.so.0.8.15
:33a2c13000-33a2e13000 ---p 00013000 08:02 24544                          /usr/lib64/libexslt.so.0.8.15
:33a2e13000-33a2e14000 rw-p 00013000 08:02 24544                          /usr/lib64/libexslt.so.0.8.15
:3df1c00000-3df1db5000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 27668                          /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.1e
:3df1db5000-3df1fb5000 ---p 001b5000 08:02 27668                          /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.1e
:3df1fb5000-3df1fd0000 r--p 001b5000 08:02 27668                          /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.1e
:3df1fd0000-3df1fdc000 rw-p 001d0000 08:02 27668                          /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.1e
:3df1fdc000-3df1fe0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
:3df2000000-3df2061000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 27669                          /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.1e
:3df2061000-3df2260000 ---p 00061000 08:02 27669                          /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.1e
:3df2260000-3df2264000 r--p 00060000 08:02 27669                          /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.1e
:3df2264000-3df226b000 rw-p 00064000 08:02 27669                          /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.1e
:3df2400000-3df2536000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 3723                          /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.16.0.0
:3df2536000-3df2735000 ---p 00136000 08:02 3723                          /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.16.0.0
:3df2735000-3df2783000 rw-p 00135000 08:02 3723                          /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.16.0.0
:3df2783000-3df2784000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
:3df2800000-3df2851000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 27674                          /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4.1.1
:3df2851000-3df2a51000 ---p 00051000 08:02 27674                          /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4.1.1
:3df2a51000-3df2a54000 rw-p 00051000 08:02 27674                          /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4.1.1
:3df2c00000-3df2c27000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 27673                          /usr/lib64/libssh2.so.1.0.1
:3df2c27000-3df2e26000 ---p 00027000 08:02 27673                          /usr/lib64/libssh2.so.1.0.1
:3df2e26000-3df2e27000 rw-p 00026000 08:02 27673                          /usr/lib64/libssh2.so.1.0.1
:3df2e27000-3df2e28000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
:3df3400000-3df3507000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 27671                          /usr/lib64/libc-client.so.2007
:3df3507000-3df3707000 ---p 00107000 08:02 27671                          /usr/lib64/libc-client.so.2007
:3df3707000-3df3711000 rw-p 00107000 08:02 27671                          /usr/lib64/libc-client.so.2007
:3df3711000-3df3712000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
:3e45400000-3e45403000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 25574                          /lib64/libcom_err.so.2.1
:3e45403000-3e45602000 ---p 00003000 08:02 25574                          /lib64/libcom_err.so.2.1
:3e45602000-3e45603000 r--p 00002000 08:02 25574                          /lib64/libcom_err.so.2.1
:3e45603000-3e45604000 rw-p 00003000 08:02 25574                          /lib64/libcom_err.so.2.1
:3e45800000-3e45841000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 25796                          /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
:3e45841000-3e45a41000 ---p 00041000 08:02 25796                          /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
:3e45a41000-3e45a42000 r--p 00041000 08:02 25796                          /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
:3e45a42000-3e45a44000 rw-p 00042000 08:02 25796                          /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
:3e45c00000-3e45cdb000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 25795                          /lib64/libkrb5.so.3.3
:3e45cdb000-3e45eda000 ---p 000db000 08:02 25795                          /lib64/libkrb5.so.3.3
:3e45eda000-3e45ee4000 r--p 000da000 08:02 25795                          /lib64/libkrb5.so.3.3
:3e45ee4000-3e45ee6000 rw-p 000e4000 08:02 25795                          /lib64/libkrb5.so.3.3
:3ef3000000-3ef3020000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 26691                          /lib64/ld-2.12.so
:3ef321f000-3ef3220000 r--p 0001f000 08:02 26691                          /lib64/ld-2.12.so
:3ef3220000-3ef3221000 rw-p 00020000 08:02 26691                          /lib64/ld-2.12.so`

`:7f656376a000-7f656376c000 rw-p 001c0000 08:02 26726                      /usr/lib64/php/modules/fileinfo.so
:7f656376c000-7f6563786000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 5404                      /usr/lib64/php/modules/eaccelerator.so
:7f6563786000-7f6563985000 ---p 0001a000 08:02 5404                      /usr/lib64/php/modules/eaccelerator.so
:7f6563985000-7f6563987000 rw-p 00019000 08:02 5404                      /usr/lib64/php/modules/eaccelerator.so
:7f6563987000-7f65639ab000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 27247                      /usr/lib64/php/modules/dom.so
:7f65639ab000-7f6563bab000 ---p 00024000 08:02 27247                      /usr/lib64/php/modules/dom.so
:7f6563bab000-7f6563bb1000 rw-p 00024000 08:02 27247                      /usr/lib64/php/modules/dom.so
:7f6563bb1000-7f6563bb8000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 26704                      /lib64/librt-2.12.so
:7f6563bb8000-7f6563db7000 ---p 00007000 08:02 26704                      /lib64/librt-2.12.so
:7f6563db7000-7f6563db8000 r--p 00006000 08:02 26704                      /lib64/librt-2.12.so
:7f6563db8000-7f6563db9000 rw-p 00007000 08:02 26704                      /lib64/librt-2.12.so
:7f6563db9000-7f6563dc8000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 21504                      /usr/lib64/php/modules/curl.so
:7f6563dc8000-7f6563fc7000 ---p 0000f000 08:02 21504                      /usr/lib64/php/modules/curl.so
:7f6563fc7000-7f6563fc9000 rw-p 0000e000 08:02 21504                      /usr/lib64/php/modules/curl.so
:7f6563fc9000-7f65640b2000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 20897                      /usr/lib64/php/modules/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so
:7f65640b2000-7f65641b1000 ---p 000e9000 08:02 20897                      /usr/lib64/php/modules/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so
:7f65641b1000-7f65641c1000 rw-p 000e8000 08:02 20897                      /usr/lib64/php/modules/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so
:7f65641c1000-7f6564213000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
:7f6564254000-7f6564261000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
:7f656426c000-7f656426d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
:7fff3957a000-7fff3958f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
:7fff395ff000-7fff39600000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
:ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]`

`open_fds:
:0:socket:[879992203]
:pos:    0
:flags:    02
:1:/var/log/httpd/error_log
:pos:    2640468
:flags:    02102001
:2:/var/log/httpd/error_log
:pos:    2640468
:flags:    02102001
:3:socket:[879993102]
:pos:    0
:flags:    02`

Please suggest what went wrong?

Comment: what are you using LAMP ?

Comment: Yes, Linux, PHP with Mysql on apache web server. plesk is the control panel.